# How do you publish an App Store application in mulitple languages?

Tags: windows-runtime, package, embedded-resource

I've got an Windows 8.1 (Modern UI) Application that has support for French and Spanish.  If I set the OS language to French or Spanish and run my application in the debugger, the application appears to find the correct language resource dlls and runs in the desired language.  I've recently published my application (in English only) to the App Store.  When I go to my test machine, change the language to Spanish, download the application from the store, I get English.  Same thing happens if I set the OS language to French.  Is there some trick to packaging the bundle before I publish or do I need to go to the Dev Center and add French and Spanish in the Submission to publish?

**Edit:** In the package manifest, I've added the section:

```
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="en" />
    <Resource Language="es" />
    <Resource Language="fr" />
  </Resources>
```

And I've add Spanish (es) and French (fr) Languages to the Submission to the Dev Center.  Still, when I load the app from the App Store onto a Spanish Windows 10 Session, I'm still only seeing the English string constants.

Comment: What method are you using to publish to the store? Directly in VS? Or creating a package and uploading it to the Dev Center?

Comment: I create a package and upload it to the Dev Center.  I see no 'Publish' option in Visual Studio.  How do you publish directly from VS?

Comment: When you create the package, you need to make sure that the languages are selected as supported, otherwise the system does not store those parts of the app package.

Comment: If you've got a suggestion that's different from my edit (above), then please post it as an answer and I'll try it out.

Comment: Did you add those manually? Are you using the Multilingual App Toolkit to define the supported languages? Have you made sure that all of the languages in the store definition have all of the necessary components, like summaries, localized screenshots, etc? I would check out [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Introducing-Windows-8/Submitting-your-localized-app-to-the-Store) and make sure you're doing all of the steps.